# Unpack *args for use in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, python-3.6

Here is my starting point. This works as is.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
l3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]


def interleave(iterable1, iterable2):
    for item1, item2 in zip(iterable1, iterable2):
        yield item1
        yield item2


print(interleave(l1, l2))
print('-' * 30)
print(list(interleave(l1, l2)))
```

If I want to expand it to use all three lists, I can do this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
l3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]


def interleave(*args):
    for item1, item2, item3 in zip(*args):
        yield item1
        yield item2
        yield item3


print(interleave(l1, l2, l3))
print('-' * 30)
print(list(interleave(l1, l2, l3)))
```

However, I 'solved' the issue of receiving any number of input iterables using
*args, but my item assignment is still manual.

I want to be able to say:

```
def interleave(*args):
    for *items in zip(*args):
        yield items
```

To allow me to unpack any number of input variables into *items, but I get this error:
    `SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple`

I don't want to say `*items = <something>`.  I want to have *items receive any number of input variables.

If I have six lists I don't want to say item1, item2, ..., item6, followed by the same number of yields.

That really isn't very scalable.

Is there a way to do what I am after?

Comment: That was it.  'yield from'.  Time to look it up.

Comment: You can just use `from itertools import chain; chain.from_iterable(zip(*args))` you know.

Answer (score 2):

For Python prior to 3.3, use a nested for loop.

```
def interleave(*args):
    for items in zip(*args):
        for item in items:
            yield item
```

For Python 3.3+ you can use `yield from` for [generator delegation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) which is syntactical sugar for the above.

```
def interleave(*args):
    for items in zip(*args):
        yield from items
```

Or finally, if you need a more general solution that permits lists of different lengths, use the `roundrobin` function from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested loop?

```
def interleave(*args):
    for items in zip(*args): 
        for item in items:
            yield items
```